# How to convert a TypeCode to an actual type?

Tags: c#, types

In the code below I get `colType` which is a code number for the type. But how would I convert that number into the actual type? Thx!!

```
for (int j = 0; j < dvColumns.Count; j++)
{
    // Get the name of the column.
    drvCols = dvColumns[j];
    colName = drvCols.Row.ItemArray[3].ToString();

    // Get columns data type code and save it off.
    colType = Convert.ToInt32(drvCols.Row.ItemArray[11]);
}
```

Comment: Give an example of the input.

Comment: You'll have to use a switch-case on the value of colType.

Comment: The problem is I don't know what type number stands for what type. For example, one of the numbers returned is 72. How can I tell what type 72 is supposed to represent?

Comment: @user259286 You can just cast it to TypeCode. See the update to my answer below.

Comment: You are the only one who can possibly know what the values of the returned numbers mean. If you don't know this, how can anyone else? Who was responsible for putting the numbers in that particular column? Ask them.

Comment: @user259286 Are you sure you are working with the System.TypeCode enumeration? There is no value 72 defined for that enumeration.

Comment: This `drvCols.Row.ItemArray[11]` is the Data Column Type. It is generated when someone creates a table, but when someone else is trying to get the type of the column, it could be any type. It is not an actual data value, it's a representation of Type.

Comment: Do you have anything in your code or documentation that maps these values to the .NET types they are supposed to represent? An enumeration defined in the code perhaps? Or are these ADO data types (http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=97)?

Comment: These are ADO datatypes. yes, I see 72 there in the URL! And it matched the column I'm seeing. So then all I need to do is box it as OleDBType.

Comment: @user259286 OK, maybe you should update the question to be more specific then. =]

Comment: @user259286 Yep, I think that will work. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 24):

It's even simpler:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("System." + colType);
```

If you want to convert a value to that type you can use the typecode directly

```
Convert.ChangeType(value, colType);
```

Comment: see the one liner exact answer to the question that I wrote below using schoetbi's hint and `Enum.GetName(typeof(TypeCode)` at
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30780954/1300390

Answer (score 10):

Using a switch statement:

```
    public static Type ToType(this TypeCode code)
    {
        switch (code)
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                return typeof(bool);

            case TypeCode.Byte:
                return typeof(byte);

            case TypeCode.Char:
                return typeof(char);

            case TypeCode.DateTime:
                return typeof(DateTime);

            case TypeCode.DBNull:
                return typeof(DBNull);

            case TypeCode.Decimal:
                return typeof(decimal);

            case TypeCode.Double:
                return typeof(double);

            case TypeCode.Empty:
                return null;

            case TypeCode.Int16:
                return typeof(short);

            case TypeCode.Int32:
                return typeof(int);

            case TypeCode.Int64:
                return typeof(long);

            case TypeCode.Object:
                return typeof(object);

            case TypeCode.SByte:
                return typeof(sbyte);

            case TypeCode.Single:
                return typeof(Single);

            case TypeCode.String:
                return typeof(string);

            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                return typeof(UInt16);

            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                return typeof(UInt32);

            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                return typeof(UInt64);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This will not work on custom types though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any way to do this natively in the .NET Framework, as all the examples I've seen use a big switch statement to handle the conversion (for example: [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/163879-how-create-type-typecode)).

However, if you are trying to get the type as an intermediary step towards converting an object to that type, you could always use [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttf5d382.aspx) which accepts a `TypeCode` as a parameter.

```
double d = -1.234;
int i = (int)Convert.ChangeType(d, TypeCode.Int32);
```

Unfortunately, without seeing what you are trying to do I can't really say if `ChangeType` would be helpful or not.

EDIT:

To convert an `int` to a `OleDbType`, you can just cast it:

```
int i = 72; //72 is the value for OleDbType.Guid
if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType), i))
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType dbType = (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType)i;
    Console.WriteLine(dbType);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not defined for System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType", i);
```

Comment: It would be nice if there were `Convert.TryChangeType<T>(d, TypeCode.Int32, out T v)` only because there are instances where you might use a `switch(TypeCode)` to handle value types. Otherwise, you end up performing various checks on `d` to ensure `Convert` doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

The exact answer to the question in the OP (using *schoetbi's* hint) would be:

```
public static Type GetType(TypeCode code)
    {         
        return Type.GetType("System." + Enum.GetName(typeof(TypeCode), code));
    }
```

Comment: I've tested it and it works for me without any problems

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I like to do it.  I prefer using a static table vs. a big switch or reflection for this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Table that maps TypeCode to it's corresponding Type.
/// </summary>
static IReadOnlyDictionary<TypeCode, Type> TypeCodeToTypeMap = new Dictionary<TypeCode, Type>
{
    { TypeCode.Boolean, typeof(bool) },
    { TypeCode.Byte, typeof(byte) },
    { TypeCode.Char, typeof(char) },
    { TypeCode.DateTime, typeof(DateTime) },
    { TypeCode.DBNull, typeof(DBNull) },
    { TypeCode.Decimal, typeof(decimal) },
    { TypeCode.Double, typeof(double) },
    { TypeCode.Empty, null },
    { TypeCode.Int16, typeof(short) },
    { TypeCode.Int32, typeof(int) },
    { TypeCode.Int64, typeof(long) },
    { TypeCode.Object, typeof(object) },
    { TypeCode.SByte, typeof(sbyte) },
    { TypeCode.Single, typeof(Single) },
    { TypeCode.String, typeof(string) },
    { TypeCode.UInt16, typeof(UInt16) },
    { TypeCode.UInt32, typeof(UInt32) },
    { TypeCode.UInt64, typeof(UInt64) }
};

/// <summary>
/// Convert a TypeCode ordinal into it's corresponding Type instance.
/// </summary>
public static Type ToType(this TypeCode code)
{
    Type type = null;

    TypeCodeToTypeMap.TryGetValue(code, out type);

    return type;
}
```

Comment: `switch` is an implementation detail and easily tucked away in an extension method. The `switch` should be faster than the dictionary due to compilation rather than run-time decoding through a map. Still, I do like the flexibility of these types of maps.

Comment: A long time ago when I was deep into C++, Scott Meyers taught me that switch statements typically run O(n) whereas we can often do better.  So I tend to use maps/dictionaries/hash tables not only for readability, but for usually O(1) performance.  I'd like to profile this to see what it really matters in C#.

Comment: Well it turns out they are comparable. In Release build, the switch has a very slight edge over the Dictionary. In Debug build (if one cares) the Dictionary actually beats the switch quite a bit. Very interesting. My takeaway is that the compiler optimizes switches to behave more like hashtables.  So performance-wise it's a wash. Do what you think is more readable. https://gist.github.com/BrandonLWhite/d823dcbddc256be6fd879b7be7d3960f